# Dropbox API uploading files

Tags: ios, dropbox

I'm trying to upload an edited version of a .txt file to Dropbox using the API for iOS but I can't seem to figure out how to use the ParentRev part of the API call. The call I am using is

```
[[self restClient] uploadFile:dropboxFilename toPath:dropboxDirectory withParentRev:[dropboxDirectory stringByAppendingString:dropboxFilename] fromPath:localDirectory];
```

dropboxFilename is the title of the file in dropbox.
dropboxDirectory is the location of the file in dropbox.
localDirectory is the path for the file on the device.

If I use 'nil' the upload works fine but it creates a new file called "example (1).txt" (of course).
But if I try to set the previous version of the file it returns a 500 error.

I haven't been able to find any documentation online on how to use ParentRev properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out ParentRev is not the previous file name like I thought. It's just a value you retrieve from the meta-data you can download for the file.

Comment: Any idea how to use `ParentRev`?